# How do I fill a newly created column with UUID using flask-migrate?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I have added a new column to my SQLAlchemy model and generated the migration script with flask-migrate.

I want to populate this new column with a random UUID for every row in my table.

Is this possible in flask-migrate?